# Swift 4 back button doesn't appear

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have problem... i have two ViewControllers and i use this code to pass from 1st VC to 2nd

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EVSignInViewController") as! EVSignInViewController
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem is.. i want to display back button on 2nd VC. I already tried use Editor->Embed in-> Navigation controller on 1st VC. Also i use this

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

Comment: Is the first VC wrapped in a navigation controller?

Comment: @Scriptable yes.. Look, i want to create back action without connect Views on Storyboard. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Presenting` a ViewController will present it modally over the top of your current one. It doesn't actually push it onto the navigation controllers navigation stack.

You either need to `push` the view controller instead

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

or wrap it in a navigation controller and then present it

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EVSignInViewController") as! EVSignInViewController
let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newViewController)
self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What should i put on 2nd VC?

Comment: If you present it, you would likely be better placing a cross or close icon in the navigation bar in the 2nd VC. if you push, you shouldn't need to do anything in 2nd VC

Comment: I create new project to test solution... 
1st solution
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true) 
doesn't show me 2nd VC at all..

Your 2nd solution pass to 2nd view but back button still missing

Comment: your first view controller might not have a navigation controller then. presenting wont give you a back button. you add a close button

Comment: my god.. forgot navigation controller, it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for present 2nd VC.

> self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)

instead of this

> self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

You will get back button.

Comment: I change present to self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true), now it doesn't show me 2nd VC

Comment: it should work. Might it be another issue. Try freshly in sample project.

Comment: What should i put on 2nd VC?

Comment: when you calling 2nd VC. what it showing? And also check Identifier for 2nd view controller.

Comment: I do create new project.. with present work fine but back button is missing.
When i use push it happens nothing.. ID is correct!
2nd VC contain
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"back", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)

Comment: Just remove 2nd VC Code. And check. Don't set manually. NavigationController will show back button for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: The user has already done this: `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)` it is not that it is hidden

Comment: try to use it in viewWillAppear of 2nd Viewcontroller